# Android AlarmManager not firing at set time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, countdowntimer

I have an `AlarmManager` that is supposed to fire off on the 26th of December 2013. Here is my code:

```
    FestCountdownTimer countdownNotificationTimer = new FestCountdownTimer(
            00, 00, 9, 26, 11, 2013);
    long timeToEvent = countdownNotificationTimer.getIntervalMillis();
    System.out
            .println("TIME TO EVENT!!! ------------------ " + timeToEvent);

        Intent eventAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToEvent, PendingIntent
                .getBroadcast(this, 1, eventAlarm,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

But, my alarm is firing off after 1 or 2 minutes. I don't know what seems to be wrong. (Byt the way, the `FestCountdownTimer` is a class I made to get the interval between now and the future set date. The `long timeToEvent;` is coming properly.)

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know about your FestCountdownTimer  class but damn sure
>   probablay time not set properly(I mean may be mistaken convert time to
>   millisecond)

Note:   **This below code is harcode not tested by in actual app**

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(year,month,day,hour,min); //set your date here 

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
   // cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: but I want the difference between the two dates... Isn't that how the alarmmanager works?

Comment: thanks it works, now how do i make sure the alarm doesn't go off after the date is done??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29  check this make sure pending intent is same whose started .. @ADeveloper